# How to serialize IEnumerable of Anonymous Type in C# to JavaScript Object?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, serialization

In my ASP.net C# code, I have an IEnumerable container filled with objects of an anonymous type (which is loosely based on data from SQL).

Suppose that my code looks something like this:

```
var uics = entities.getData()
    .Select(x => new
        {
            id = x.id
            name = x.name
            age = x.age
        });
return Json(uics); //Serialize JSON in ASP.net MVC 3
```

This is very simple.  When I serialize this to JavaScript, I get an array of objects, each having fields id, name, and age.

What I would like to do is serialize this data to a JavaScript Object with id as the index, with each object referenced by its index having fields name and age.

How can I accomplish this.

Comment: You mean you want an array, basically? So that the json will look like: `[ "id1" : {name: name1, age: age1} , "id2" : {name, name2: age: age2}]` ?

Comment: The JSON should look something like what you describe, @Alexander

Comment: Maybe this blog post can be of any help :

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/09/Using-an-alternate-JSON-Serializer-in-ASPNET-Web-API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `IDictionary` and use it as the result of the action:

```
var uics = entities.getData()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => new { x.name, x.age });

return Json(uics); //Serialize JSON in ASP.net MVC 3
```

There is no need to explicitly specify the property names for the anonymous type used here, because the compiler defaults those to the name of the property used to provide a value (which in both cases here is the same).

Comment: +1: This is the answer I'm looking for.  I would like to add that I discovered as I implemented this answer that if your dictionary key is a strongly-typed GUID, you must first cast it to a string.